# Something is not working in my property setter

Tags: python, numpy

I was testing properties in Python and I found a weird behaviour in my program. Suppose this piece of code:

```
import numpy

class ClassEnc(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.__x = numpy.ones((10,1))
        pass

    @property
    def x(self):
        print "getter"
        return self.__x

    @x.setter
    def x(self,val):
        print "setter"
        self.__x = val



obj = ClassEnc()
obj.x[0:2] = numpy.zeros((2,1))
print obj.x[0:2]
obj.x = 2
```

Given that program, I would expect this output:

```
setter        #The first asignment
getter        #The print access
[ 0.  0.  1.] #The print output
setter        #The second asignment
```

But the real output is:

```
getter     #WHY?!
getter
[ 0.  0.  1.]
setter
```

I would appreciate any clue on this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`obj.x[0:2] = numpy.zeros((2,1))` doesn't assign to `x`.

It gets `x` then assigns to a slice of `x`.